# Менеджер контактов с помощью knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, html5, knockoutjs

Добрый день.

Столкнулся с двумя проблемами: 
1. Форма исчезает, когда я добавляю блок кода там, где можно отредактировать контакт. Хочу, чтобы она загружалась изначально, и я бы смог добавлять новый контакт, а сейчас она не показывается. Когда в теге <form> удаляю data-bind="with: selectedItem" - все показывается, но соответсвенно не работает биндинг
2. Не могу осуществить live search (блок кода search закомментирован).

Вот код: http://jsfiddle.net/ovesyan19/uc8ubcy8/1/

Особенно волнует первый вопрос!